# How much time does Googlebot take to crawl the page after submitting it to index

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot

I've a daily changing job site and I've also setup a dynamically generated XML sitemap for the search engines. But Googlebot indexes the at it's own priority.

I've a page linking to newly added jobs which I want Googlebot to index ASAP.

I've observed that after giving a page "Submit to index" in "Fetch as Google" in GWT Google may take 2-3 days to index it.

Has Google released any official update about how much time it'd take to index a page after we "Add to index" in the GWT?

I've tried to search in Google about this query but I found nothing ...

Comment: _"Add to index" in the GWT_ - Maybe a localisation/translation thing, but I assume you mean the "Submit to index" option? "Submit..." would be more accurate since there is no guarantee that the page(s) will be added to the index at all. Also, your title is a bit misleading - the crawling of a page does not necessarily reflect the index status of that page, which seems to be your main question. (Although, you can monitor the crawl rate of your page by analysing your own access logs.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is impossible to answer based on facts because every site is treated differently from one to the next. The time it takes for Google to return to a site is very complex algorithm which has countless variables that will affect the crawl back date:

- Your Niche will play some role in how important it believes your content is.
- Your site speed plays some role.
- Your backlinks, social mentions - if your adding content that happens to get linked from various trusted sites your get a update within minutes not hours or days.

Comment: You want to say in short that it's all variable. Googlebot will still take it's own time?

Comment: Pretty much. Submit your latest sitemap file and wait 1 day to 3 weeks. Plenty of other things in life to be paying attention to. The watched pot takes longer to boil.

Answer (score 2):

Like you've said it does take 2-3 days usually but can be up-to a few weeks. Pages of mine that I uploaded when I uploaded my website a few weeks ago are still getting crawled and then getting added to index.

Maybe if you submit your jobs to an established job website with a link back to yours it would help?

Answer (score 1):

The way that Google works is that it goes to other pages through links in pages it already knows.

Basically Google's bot will discover pages at the same rate that users find them, you need to have one link from a page that Google knows. If you sign up for Webmaster Tools then this speeds the process up. If you do that it usually takes only 2-3 days to get it crawled.